# Complete android configuration details

Tags: android, backup

I am trying to work on a project which requires to take backup of complete android configration say wifi connection list and pwd's, ringtone, screen brightness, bookmarks, etc. Is there any common place that android stores them or do we individually need to extract them and revert then in case of lost phone or factory reset?